# What's wrong with my C# For Loop and If statement?

Tags: c#, .net

```
int LetterCount = 0;
string strText = "Debugging";
string letter;

for (int i = 0; i <strText.Length; i++)
{
  letter = strText.Substring(0, 9);
  if(letter == "g")
  {    
    LetterCount++;
    textBox1.Text = "g appears " + LetterCount + " times";
  }
}
```

So, I'm doing this tutorial thing, and I've been stuck on this exercise for like 4 hours.  And I can't figure out what's wrong with my For Loop.

The point of the exercise is to make my program thing tell me how many g's are in the word debugging.  But you probably figured that out.  Anyway, I'm not even sure that I have the right code for telling me that, because I think that I need to change the second part of the For Loop (the i < ) part.

But my problem is that it isn't registering the "if letter == "g" " at all. Because according to my locals window it says that letter=Debugging, which would make me think that g should be registering on my program 24 times, I think (because `str.length` is 9 letters long?)  But it's registering as 0 no matter what I do.

Comment: BTW, you should also consider using string.Equals when comparing two strings, because you can set whether comparison should be case and linguistically sensitive.

Comment: You don't need to update that text box every time you run through the loop. Move this line after your for loop. textBox1.Text = "g appears " + LetterCount + " times";

Comment: Omg.  So, the tutorial was stupid.  It told me to put 0, 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are extracting a string of 9 characters. It will never be equal to "g" (which only has one). Here's how I'd do it.

```
int count = 0;
foreach (char c in strText)
{
    if (c == 'g')
       count++;
}
```

Using the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strText.Length; i++)
{
    if (strText[i] == 'g')
       count++;
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan, the downside to this is it's a **foreach** not a **for** loop, so the OP won't gain an understanding of a "plain vanilla" for loop from it, which I'd guess is the main intent of the tutorial they're following; or at least the current section =)

Comment: I would probably do the loop in just one line just to impress the teacher: `foreach (char c in strText) if (c == 'g') count++;` :o)

Comment: @Rob: Well, I did point out what seems to be the primary error in my mind. As indicated, that's just probably the approach I'd take. But, yes, if this is some sort of school assignment, hey may not yet be familiar with `foreach`.

Comment: @balexandre: Heh, well in that case, perhaps you'd like a compact LINQ statement.

Comment: added code if he needs to use the `for` loop instead the `foreach`

Comment: @balexandre: Note that `strText.SubString(i, 1)` is considerably less efficient than `strText[i]`.

Comment: It's just something I'm self teaching myself, but apparently the tutorial blows. It told me to put 0,1 and then told me to go from there.  But the tutorial hadn't even gotten to substrings yet.  Sooo.  Yeah.  Anyway thank you so much for your help. (:  Do I have to accept an answer or something now?  Or do I just let it fade away?

Comment: @Cole: Well, `Substring(i, 1)` would work, although it's less efficient, as I pointed out above. If you want people to help you in the future, it's a good idea to accept the answer you find helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the documentation for [string.Substring(x, y)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

Basically:

```
letter = strText.Substring(0, 9);
```

Isn't giving you a letter. Each time through it's giving you all 9 characters of the string `strText`. **You might want to consider using the variable `i` for one of the values you pass to Substring.**

*(I've deliberately not given you the entire answer as you seem to want to understand, so, if the pointers I've given don't get you there, let me know and I'll expand my answer =)*

Comment: Well I had 0,1, but that was just getting me stuck at D.  I think the tutorial I was reading was wrong, because it told me to put 0, 1.  But putting i, 1 fixed it. Thank you :D <3

Comment: @Cole, glad I could help =) It sounds very much like the tutorial you're working through had a typo (or three)! Oh and welcome to stackoverflow =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <strText.Length; i++)
    {

       if(strText[i] == 'g')
       {
         LetterCount++;
       }
    }
    textBox1.Text = "g appears " + LetterCount + " times";
```

The issue is that you are looking at the entire string when you compare to "g".  By specifying an index you are telling it to look at a specific character in the string.  Also, I removed your substring because it did not appear to be doing anything.

Comment: I think you meant `letter[i] == 'g'`.

Comment: Not sure that your first line is correct, more or less, you've just copied the value of strText.  Did you mean to use .ToCharArray() instead?

Comment: @ben, no I didn't plan on using `ToCharArray`.  Which part is it that you think is not correct? The `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `i` at all in your `for` loop.

Do you mean

```
letter = strText.Substring(i, 1);
```

?

Comment: I'm fairly blind.  I couldn't tell if it was an I or a 1 on the tutorial :[

Comment: Happens more and more as you get older. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are taking substring that is long 9 charachters and comparing it to "g". It won't be equal.

You should try:

```
letter = strText.Substring(i,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [String.Substring(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) takes two arguments: the offset and amount to take.

In your case, `letter = strText.Substring(0, 9);` will simply assign letter's value to "Debugging". If you want to check each letter individually, you need to write `letter = strText.Substring(i, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
int LetterCount = 0;
string strText = "Debugging";
string letter;

for (int i = 0; i <strText.Length; i++)
{
  letter = strText.Substring(i, 1);
  if(letter == "g")
  {    
    LetterCount++;
    textBox1.Text = "g appears " + LetterCount + " times";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

letter = strText.Substring(0, 9);

at this point, 'letter' has the value "Debugging" since you're taking the entire string.

Try `letter = strText[i]` so you isolate the single letter.

Answer (score 0):

What @Rob said.

Try something like this:

```
int    gCount = 0;
string s      = "Debugging";

for ( int i = 0; i <strText.Length; i++)
{
  if ( s[i] == 'g' ) ++gCount ;
}
textBox1.Text = "g appears " + gCount+ " times";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace runtime
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int lettercount = 0;
            string strText = "Debugging";
            string letter;


            for (int i = 0; i < strText.Length; i++)
            {
                letter = strText.Substring(i,1);

                if (letter == "g")
                {
                    lettercount++;
                }

            }
            textBox1.Text = "g appear " + lettercount + " times";
        }
    }
}
```